# Sensible group Id for individual project?

Tags: maven, naming-conventions, naming

What is a sensible choice of group Id for a maven project that does not fall under any company/organisation/website? I understand that the convention com.companyname.projectname is used in order to avoid namespace conflicts between projects, but how should I come up with a prefix for an individual project I am starting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the [official guide:](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html)

> **groupId** will identify your project uniquely across all projects, so we
>   need to enforce a naming schema. It has to follow the package name
>   rules, what means that has to be at least as a domain name you
>   control, and you can create as many subgroups as you want. Look at
>   More information about package names.
>
> eg. org.apache.maven, org.apache.commons
>
> A good way to determine the granularity of the groupId is to use the
>   project structure. That is, if the current project is a multiple
>   module project, it should append a new identifier to the parent's
>   groupId.
>
> eg. org.apache.maven, org.apache.maven.plugins,
>   org.apache.maven.reporting

So, just as you would do for a package name, you should ideally use domain name, that represents the project. If you don't have one, you can just imaging your project having one. So *"domain you control"* might be your personal domain, or this specific project's domain. I.e. `com.andyw.nextbigthing` or `com.nextbigthing`. If you're considering it as something, that can be interesting to be picked up by community, you can skip the personal name and use `org` instead. I.e. `org.nextbigthing`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some popular repository like GitHub you should follow [next rules](https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html):

> If your project name is foo at SourceForge, you can use **net.sf.foo**. If your username is bar on Github, you can use **com.github.bar**. You can also use another reversed domain name you control. The group ID does not have to reflect the project host.